# Error encountered when configuring csvReader to use the Avro schema registry in Apache Nifi

Tags: schema, apache-nifi, avro, csvreader

csvReader property set:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8vjC.png)

Here is the schema I created and registered in AvroSchemaRegistry

> {
> "namespace": "nifi",
> "type": "record",
> "name": "users",
> "fields" : [
> {"name": "first_name", "type": "string"},
> {"name": "last_name", "type": "string"},
> {"name": "age", "type": "int"}
> ]
> }

Error I encountered upon running the Apache-nifi processor

`org.apache.nifi.schema.access.SchemaNotFoundException: FlowFile did not contain appropriate attributes to determine Schema Text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure your CSVReader as -

`Schema Access Strategy` = `Use 'Schema Name' Property`

`Schema Registry` = `Your AvroSchemaRegistry Controller Service`

`Schema Name` = `users`

`Schema Text` = `let it be default value`

This means CSVReader will search schema registry for the specified schema name since the access strategy is the schema name, and we are passing it to the registry.

Comment: It works like a charm thanks.  By the way I'm planning to have an auto increment primary key how will configure it on the schema?  thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how and where you are using the auto increment primary key? Do you mean schema version?

Comment: In my table the primary key will get its value automatically from the sequence.  Here is the way I set the schema db.  

   ** id integer DEFAULT nextval('public.user_row_dtl_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,**

And in my CSV **id**  is not added only the firstname, lastname, age.  So my question is how will I map these attributes to the db fields using the AvroSchema?  As I tried adding the primary key it looks like I always got number exception since the first column being mapped is the firstname.